# Access post ID in "content_save_pre"

Tags: filters, globals, xml-rpc

First time poster, pardon my mistakes.

I am trying to use the `content_save_pre` filter to grab a URL in the first line of a post and save it into a custom meta, and also set the post format as a link. All of that works fine, for the most part.

```
public function save_content($content) {

    // short circuit if special ignore tag is included anywhere in content
    if ( stripos($content, "<!--ignore-->") != false ) {
        return $content;
    }

    $lines = explode("\n", $content);

    // added href handling so that HTML anchor-links can be handled
    $regex = '/(?:href="([^\s"]+))|((?:http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(?:\/\S*)?)/';

    $match = preg_match($regex, $lines[0], $matches);

    if ( $match ) {
        $url = $matches[0];
        $url = preg_replace('/&?utm_(.*?)\=[^&]+/im', '', $url);

        global $post;
        if ( $post == null || !isset($post->ID) ) {
            // this is part of the problem
            return $content;
        }

        $result = $this->common_save($post->ID, \LinkedList\Meta::SOURCE_URL, $url);

        // prevent save fields from overwriting a blank on top of just added value
        add_filter('linked_list_save_fields', function($bool){
            return false;
        });

        set_post_format($post->id, 'link');

        unset($lines[0]);
        return join("\n", $lines);

    }

    return $content;

}
```

I add the filter for that method elsewhere, but like so:

```
add_filter('content_save_pre', array($this, 'save_content'), 9, 1);
```

The problem I am having is when using the Android/iOS WordPress app, which I think is using the XML-RPC interface to the self hosted WordPress, the `global $post` is not populated, and `common_save` (a method that saves custom meta fields) and `set_post_format` do not work without it.

Is there anyway to the `$post->ID` while in the XML-RPC "content_save_pre" so this could work? I have been using the `add_action('all', ...)` to see if the XML-RPC saving actually works, and it is definitely being called, it just cannot continue because of the lack of `$post` being populated.

Another alternative I thought would be to attach a special custom meta and then use a frequently scheduled cron handle it later, but that seems complicated and I would have to dive really deep into that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After asking around and looking for alternatives, I came up with a working solution that works in the web frontend and in the Android/iOS XML-RPC based apps.

This is the filter.

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', array($this, 'save_content2'), 9, 2);
```

I am pretty sure it is called *before* the `content_save_pre` filter. It allows direct access to the post fields like the post content and the post metadata like the ID.

```
public function save_content2($data, $post) {

    $content = $data['post_content'];

    // short circuit if special ignore tag is included anywhere in content
    if ( stripos($content, "<!--ignore-->") != false ) {
        return $data;
    }

    if ( trim($content) == '' ) {
        return $data;
    }

    $lines = explode("\n", $content);

    if ( count($lines) == 0 ) {
        return $data;
    }

    // added href handling so that HTML anchor-links can be handled
    $regex = '/(?:href="([^\s"]+))|((?:http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(?:\/\S*)?)/';

    $match = preg_match($regex, $lines[0], $matches);

    if ( $match ) {
        $url = $matches[0];
        $url = preg_replace('/&?utm_(.*?)\=[^&]+/im', '', $url);

        if ( !isset($post) || !isset($post['ID']) || $post['ID'] == 0 ) {
            return $data;
        }

        $result = $this->common_save($post['ID'], \LinkedList\Meta::SOURCE_URL, $url);

        // prevent save fields from overwriting a blank on top of just added value
        add_filter('linked_list_save_fields', function($bool){
            return false;
        });

        set_post_format($post['ID'], 'link');

        unset($lines[0]);
        $data['post_content'] = join("\n", $lines);
        return $data;
    }

    return $data;

}
```

What has changed: the arguments, now the data and some post metadata like the ID, both are available here cleanly. The return values have been swapped from `$content` to `$data` and when the first line is indeed altered, the result is saved back into the `$data['post_content']` field and the entire array is returned.

While this works, any other suggestions are absolutely welcome.

Comment: I don't believe $post is available, at least not if it's a new post